# MediaElement on Windows XP & Vista vs 7

Tags: wpf, windows-7, windows-xp, directshow, mediaelement

I have a simple WinForms application (compiled for 32Bit) with a Custom WPF Control that hosts a MediaElement. The code below plays the video perfectly under Windows 7 (64 Bit) but under Vista and XP triggers the MediaFailed event with the message "Media failed to download".

`

```
this.MediaElement.LoadedBehavior = System.Windows.Controls.MediaState.Manual;  
this.MediaElement.UnloadedBehavior = System.Windows.Controls.MediaState.Manual;  
this.MediaElement.Source = new System.Uri(@"C:\Video\Video.mp4", System.UriKind.Absolute);  

this.MediaElement.Position = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);  
this.MediaElement.Play();
```

`

The video is fine and plays in Windows Media Player on all three OS's. The video is H.264/MPEG-4/AVC encoded. Could this be a DirectShow filter issue? If not, what else can I look into to get this running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it just about is guaranteed to be a DS filter issue.  For what ever reason the codec on that machine doesnt recognise the mp4 file.

if you use graphedit on the machine that doesnt work with your mp4 file and compare it to the machine that does work, you will see if the filter (codec) is loading or not

[graphedit link](http://www.videohelp.com/download/graphedit10-090724.zip)

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a try right now. By the way, would you know how I could extract more detailed information from the RoutedEventArgs regarding the failure. This is the first time I am working with WPF so my initial search wasn't too fruitful.

Comment: Is there a way to restrict the MediaElement to use a specific filter?

Comment: yes there is, but its not particularly easy.  You need to build the directshow filter graph yourself in code.  To do this you need to use wpfmediakit instead of mediaelement.  http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/.  Then to build the filtergraph you need directshow.net http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/.  This will be a complex task.  or if you are just running your app on 1 machine, then you can go and manually adjust the codec priority with a codec priority tool ( google will help here )